# Alternative tokens (not, and, etc...) in VisualStudio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

The "not", "and", etc... are keywords in C++ (macros in C). Is there any way to "enable" them in Visual Studio 2013? I'm able to use the words as macroses with `iso646.h` included. But VS seems not be able to recognize them as keywords.

Comment: *I'm able to use the words as macroses with iso646.h included. But VS seems not be able to recognize them as keywords.* Are you saying it works but you don't get syntax highlighting?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: He's saying that in C++ it should recognize them as keywords *without* a header, but right now he has to use a header to get it to recognize them.

Comment: Keep in mind that "VS" is Visual Studio which is not a compiler. *But VS seems not be able to recognize them as keywords.* And if what you say is correct, that's totally expected according to the manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k6w8551.aspx *The not operator is the text equivalent of !. There are two ways to access the not operator in your programs: include the header file iso646.h, or compile with the /Za (Disable language extensions) compiler option.*

Comment: Try with the /Za option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `/Za` seems to enable them without including `iso646.h`, [see it live](http://rextester.com/TRT75517), the following program produces an error without using `/Za` but works fine otherwise:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 0 ;
    if (x and y)    
    {
    //...  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As ta.speot.is indicates [/Za](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) disables extensions, the following [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx) indicates you must include `ios646.h` otherwise:

> Under /Ze, you have to include iso646.h if you want to use text forms of the following operators:

and it lists the alternative tokens below.

Note, I knew I saw this before, I include a link to a [bug report for this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/312168/still-no-support-for-keywords-like-and-in-vc) in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18186331/1708801) to a similar question. Although this does not include the workaround noted above.

Note 2: Cheers and hth. - Alf indicates that there may be many undesirable consequences to turning off extension and therefore you may be better off just including `iso646.h`.

Comment: it's not a good idea to to turn off visual c++ extensions, because then it's likely that much microsoft code will not compile. instead use a forced include of iso646.h

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thank you for the comment, adjusted answer. I am curious do you have any examples?

Comment: like, including `<windows.h>` fails.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [forced include (option `/FI`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx) of the `iso646.h` header.

For work in the command interpreter you can put this in your `CL` environment variable, or e.g. in a response file.

---

Turning off Visual C++ language extensions with `/Za` can also do the trick, at the cost of rendering the compiler pretty much ***useless*** – since Microsoft code such as the Windows API headers generally uses the extensions.

Answer (score 1):

On a more recent version of VS (tested on Version 15.7.0 Preview 3.0); ensure that conformance mode is set for visual studio:
[image]

It then compiles with the [alternative operator representations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative).