# Visual Studio is not creating temporary object when typecasting?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, casting, temporary-objects, const-reference

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 and is fooling around a bit trying to learn about different things in C++.

I stumbled upon an interesting bug in the compiler where it doesn't seem to create a temporary object when explicitly type casting to the same type as the reference.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number; // float number;
    number = 2;

    const int& plainref_i = number;
    const int& recastref_i = (int)number; // this goes wrong if number is int
    const float& plainref_f = number;
    const float& recastref_f = (float)number; // this goes wrong if number is float

    number = 3;

    std::cout << plainref_i << "\n";
    std::cout << recastref_i << "\n";
    std::cout << plainref_f << "\n";
    std::cout << recastref_f << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This will when compiled in VS, results in the following output:
3 
3
2
2

But compiled with gcc, results in the following output:
3
2
2
2

If I replace "int number;" with "float number;" I get in VS:
2
2
3
3

and with gcc:
2
2
3
2

I'm wondering if anyone can confirm this as a bug and if anyone knows of a feasible workaround/solution.

Comment: Sounds similar to [Is the result of a cast an rvalue?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26508609/1708801) ... using `/Zc:rvalueCast ` seems to fix the behavior

Comment: @Remy: How on earth are those two a duplicate? I'll have what you're having, mate!

Comment: It's similar yeah, thanks. And it also gives me the solution.
But I wouldn't call it a pure duplicate.
The other question doesn't cover that error only occurs when casting to the same type as the original object and not when casting to another type.

Comment: Does this still happen when you use the appropriate C++ style casts instead of C casts? (Just curious)

Comment: Yes, using static_cast will give the same error.
I'm just using C cast because I'm lazy.

Comment: @dnfs it is not a duplicate and I was not the one who closed it as such. I did not have time to answer at the moment but I was pretty sure that question was related so I left the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
 int number;
```

The results of this cast should be a prvalue:

```
const int& recastref_i = (int)number; // this goes wrong if number is int
```

and since you are using const reference then it can bind to the prvalue and its value should be divorced from any changes to `number` but Visual Studio has an [extension which produces an lvalue instead of a prvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26508755/1708801), so you actually receive an lvalue reference to `number` which means any changes in value to `number` will be reflected when checking the value of `recastref_i`.

The Visual Studio team recommends using the `/Zc:rvalueCast` flag to turn off this behavior (*emphasis mine*):

> When the /Zc:rvalueCast option is specified, the compiler correctly
>   identifies an rvalue reference type as the result of a cast operation
>   in accordance with the C++11 standard. When the option is not
>   specified, the compiler behavior is the same as in Visual Studio 2012.
>   By default, /Zc:rvalueCast is off. **For conformance and to eliminate
>   errors in the use of casts, we recommend that you use /Zc:rvalueCast.**

as opposed to `/Za` which will disable all extensions which [can be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008049/not-and-etc-in-visualstudio-2013/26008150#comment40733011_26008150) in practical scenarios.

From the draft C++ standard section `5.4` *Explicit type conversion (cast notation)* paragraph *1* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> The result of the expression (T) cast-expression is of type T. The
>   result is an lvalue if T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue
>   reference to function type and an xvalue if T is an rvalue reference
>   to object type; **otherwise the result is a prvalue.**