# My Visual studio 2013 compiler for C++ is not working correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++-2013

I have C++ compiler issues on Visual Studio 2013. I am learning C++ for the C++ 11 standard and I was given this program that compiles perfectly on every other C++ 11 compiler.

VS 2013 however is giving me issue. It tells me `Error: identifier "not" is undefined` (where it says `// line 36` in code). I am not sure how to fix this.  I have tried to check macros and I am still having issues getting to compile:

```cpp
///     Sort the standard input alphabetically.
/*    Read lines of text, sort them, and print the results to the standard output.
     If the command line names a file, read from that file. Otherwise, read from
   the standard input. The entire input is stored in memory, so don’t try
    this with input files that exceed available RAM.
*/
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
void read(std::istream& in, std::vector<std::string>& text)
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(in, line))
        text.push_back(line);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Part 1. Read the entire input into text. If the command line names a file,
    // read that file. Otherwise, read the standard input.
    std::vector<std::string> text; ///< Store the lines of text here
    if (argc < 2)
        read(std::cin, text);
    else
    {
        std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
//line 36
        if (not in)
        {
            std::perror(argv[1]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        read(in, text);
    }
    // Part 2. Sort the text.
    std::sort(text.begin(), text.end());
    // Part 3. Print the sorted text.
    std::copy(text.begin(), text.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: See [not, and, etc… in VisualStudio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26008049/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That must be a hard title to search for in Google :P

Comment: That fixed it. thanks! @ShafikYaghmour

Comment: @CoryKramer yeah, that title could use some work.