# 'or' fails to be recognized?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am an absolute newbie in Windows (I usually work on macOS/Linux).

I am trying to help my student to compile my C++ code in Windows but we are not succeeding. We have narrowed the problem down to this minimal example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int i = 10;

  if ( i == 10 or i == 100 )
    std::cout << "..." << std::endl;
}
```

This gives the error

```
cl /std:c++14 so.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.13.26131.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

so.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include\xlocale(313): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
so.cpp(7): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'or'
so.cpp(7): error C2065: 'or': undeclared identifier
so.cpp(7): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'i'
so.cpp(7): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
so.cpp(8): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'std::cout'
so.cpp(7): warning C4553: '==': operator has no effect; did you intend '='?
```

Comment: You can use || instead.

Comment: @Héctor `or` is a valid and should be exactly the same as `||`

Comment: A few users here should give http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative a read. [`or`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/or) is a c++ keyword.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux so the `include` suggested by Jesper isnt required? I am a little bit confused, because I always thought `and` `or` and the like are standard and dont require any special header to be included

Comment: @user463035818 as Francois said - read the link; yes you need the include

Comment: @UKMonkey now you are confusing me even more ;). The link francois gave does not have the include, but the one Jepser gave has an include, though maybe for something else ...

Comment: @UKMonkey If you read the link correclty, you'll find you do *not* need the include **in C++**. You need it in C, though.

Comment: You are not *supposed* to need that header in C++. However, in Visual Studio you need that header even in C++ code, if you want to use alternative tokens. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @AnT (and all others) Thanks a lot! My observation is that everything works if I `#include <iso646.h>`. I presume that it does not negatively effect me on other platforms?

Comment: On the more recent version of VS you can [set the conformance mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49860047/1460794).

Comment: I found I needed to `#include <ciso646>` for MSVC. It works fine with or without that for MinGW.