# Literal "or" in c++ program?

Tags: c++, c, keyword

I'm translating a C++ function I wrote some time ago into python when I noticed that my C++ code contains the following lines:

```c++
  if(MIsScaledOut()) {
    if(DataType()==UnknownDataType or DataType()==h)
      Descriptor = Descriptor + DataTypeString() + "OverM";
```

There's an `or` in there!  This was probably because I previously translated from python, and forgot to switch to `||`.

This code compiles in various OSes, with various compilers, and I've never seen a problem with it.  Is this standard, or have I just gotten lucky so far, and this is something I should worry about?

Comment: It's really sad that everyone is using `||` and `&&` instead of `and` and `or`.

Comment: @Elazar: What's sad is that perfectly cromulent identifiers, which appear often in logic, have been made unavailable in all scopes.

Comment: It's always fun to embiggen a language.  [Sorry; I just had to...]

Comment: It should have been opt-in through standadized compiler directive. Just like the digrams/trigrams (together with their template problems)

Comment: This is valid, although [there are some details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18186331/1708801), in C you need to include `iso646.h` and Visual Studio in not compliant in C++ and they don't plan on fixing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After remembering the right word to google, I now see that [it is listed as a C++ keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword), along with various similar keywords like `and` that I'd never seen (noticed?) before in C++.  The [reason these exist](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) is because there are encodings that don't have some of the required punctuation characters used by the traditional operator spellings: `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, `#`, `\`, `^`, `|`, `~`.

As @mafso points out, the alternative "spelled out" versions can be used in C by including the `<iso646.h>` header, which [defines them as macros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative#Compatibility_with_C).

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555505/c-alternative-tokens) of which this has been marked duplicate also points out the existence of [digraphs and trigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C), which can be used to substitute for the missing characters.  (That question also says "everybody knows about" them.  Obviously, I did not...)

Comment: Remember to click on the checkmark to close the question.

Comment: As this is also tagged with C, it could be noted, that they aren't keywords there (e.g. writing `int and = 42;` is legal), but are provided as macros if `<iso646.h>` is included (cf C11 (n1570) 7.9).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have to wait two days to accept my own answer.  :\

Comment: @mafso True.  It's mentioned in the second link in this answer, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit.  Thanks!