# C++ operator precedence a<b<c

Tags: c++, operators, operator-precedence

I'm trying to compare values in an if statement, but it keeps coming out wrong. Basically what I'm trying to do logically is `if (a <= b < c){ //do stuff` however I find that `a <= b` returns either a `0` or a `1` which will always be less than `c`. All I can think of is what's below but I don't know if that's correct or the simplest way.

```
if (a <= b == 1 and b < c == 1){ 
// do stuff
```

Thank you

Comment: Note [and instead of &&](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17365271/1708801) is valid if rarely used.

Comment: Don't use `and` - use `&&` for a logical and operation. `and` is in place only for keyboards where typing `&&` is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this and please learn the usage of operators beforehand.

```
if(a<=b && b<c) {
     //do stuff
}
```