# How do i add boolean in c?

Tags: c

I want to do a while loop with a boolean kind of like in python.

I want something like:

```
while(player1_health > 0 or player2_health > 0){
    //code
}
```

Comment: Perhaps getting hold of a C programming book would be a quicker way to learn the C programming language

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 3):

There is no `or` operator in `C`, In `C` we use symbol `||`, called as logical OR operator.

Use This

```
while( (player1_health > 0) || (player2_health > 0) ) {
    //code
}
```

**Update:** Looks like `C99` includes `or` , `and` for operators `||` , `&&`, if you are using `C99` it works with the inclusion of header file `#include <iso646.h>`

Comment: It is if you `#include <iso646.h>`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365271/and-and-operator-in-c

Comment: Thanks @JohnZwinck, I learned something new, updated the post, is that OK?

Comment: The 'or' from `#include <iso646.h>` is a macro, so it is not part of the language. The 'or' operator in C is `||`.